# Duplicate entry issue in magento database

Tags: magento

ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1893: Duplicate entry '179-81-0' for key 'UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DTIME_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID'

Probably you have faced the similar issue as I am.If I take the value 
'179-81-0'

I am sure 179 is the product id but not sure about other -81-0.Also in other threads it was suggested to delete the row from the table but without knowing 100% what I am doing it would be a foolish act to just delete the row.I need to know what exactly is it.

Answer (score 2):

This key is defined by table `catalog_product_entity_datetime` as follows:

```
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DTIME_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID` (
    `entity_id`,
    `attribute_id`,
    `store_id`
)
```

Hence, 179-81-0 means:

- `catalog_product_entity.entity_id` = 179
- `eav.attribute.attribute_id` = 81
- `core_store.store_id` = 0

Comment: Many thanks Jurgen for the explanation.I have sorted it out.Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help^^